# Обработка запросов с консоли в C++

Tags: c++

Как наиболее универсально сделать обработку такого запроса и подобных ему?

**You are given N integers.Then you are given 2 queries.First query consists of 1 integer denoting the position which should be removed.Next query consists of 2 integers denoting the range that should be removed.**

Самый тупой способ - захардкодить обработку сначала запроса из одного числа, затем из двух и никак иначе. Но что если запросы будут приходить в другом порядке? Можно читать каждую строку, проверять ее длину и в зависимости от длины применять `stoi` к разным частям строки. А если числа в запросе каждый раз будут разделены разным числом пробелов, как тогда выделить из строки одно или два числа?

Моя попытка решения. Не выглядит ли это как оверинжиниринг? Как улучшить программу?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

enum{FIRST, SECOND};

int query(std::vector<int>& v, int type)
{
    int start, end;
    if(type == FIRST)
    {
        std::cin >> start;
        v.erase(v.begin() + start - 1);
        return 1;
    }
    if(type == SECOND)
    {
        std::cin >> start >> end;
        v.erase(v.begin() + start - 1, v.begin() + end - 1);
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

void answer(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    if(v.size() > 0)
    {
        std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, value;  // number of elements
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    std::cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> value;
        numbers.push_back(value);
    }
    query(numbers, FIRST);
    query(numbers, SECOND);
    answer(numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, уж... Это из серии: "зачем просто, если можно сложно?"

Comment: стоит ли ради простых операций целую функцию писать? неужели нельзя все в теле функции **main** все сделать?

Comment: Пытался не только решить задачу, но еще и сделать красиво и с учетом возможных ошибок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте по порядку.

> Но что если запросы будут приходить в другом порядке?

Если запрос один в строке - то тогда можно, просто надо различать запросы из одного числа в строке и из двух. Если же нет...
Я не вижу способа выделить запросы из строки

```
3  7  12
```

Это что? 3, а потом диапазон 7-12? Или диапазон 3-7, а потом 12?
Или если запросы будут по одному числу в строке?

> Можно читать каждую строку, проверять ее длину и в зависимости от длины применять `stoi` к разным частям строки. А если числа в запросе каждый раз будут разделены разным числом пробелов, как тогда выделить из строки одно или два числа?

Здесь вы опираетесь на то, что запрос всегда в отдельной строке. Тогда я бы считывал строку, прятал ее в `istringstream`, и оттуда, как из потока, считывал - с проверкой корректности - два числа. Вот и вся недолга - считается одно число корректно - значит, элемент; обе - диапазон.

И еще - ведь не оговорено, что в запросах нумерация элементов идет с 1 - так почему вы так решили? Мне кажется, что если не сказано иное, надо использовать нумерацию с нуля.

Ну, и чтобы не нарваться на неприятности, лучше все же делать проверку корректности введенных данных - чтоб за диапазон не выскакивали...

> Не выглядит ли это как оверинжиниринг?

Не без того :)

> Как улучшить программу?

Ну, выше я немного указал. Кроме того, по моему мнению, не следует в одной функции смешивать и считывание запроса, и его выполнение. Тем более что выполнение в принципе одинаково для обоих случаев - в конце концов, один элемент - ни что иное как одноэлементный диапазон.

У вас программа интерактивная? Или данные будет считывать из файла? Если интерактивная - предусмотрите приглашения для ввода, пользователь очень легко запутается, что именно он вводит.